# Theme Check errors of theme code

Tags: theme-development, errors

We are receiving these errors while we check out theme using ThemeCheck. We never seen this before and note sure what they mean or how to solve them. Can anyone so kind to tell us about these and some details on solution please:

1. https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfbnxp4952zm8f8/0001.png?dl=0
2. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3oque6dw2ip0yo1/0002.png?dl=0

Thanks alot

Comment: Please put information like error messages and code directly into your question - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Textdomain Error

The error message mean, that you haven't a textdomain. There is required for translation of this string. In the first error message is the problem the missing textdomain on the function [`_n_noop()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n_noop).

Right usage as example below.

```
_n_noop( 'Security Release', 'Security Releases', 'your_textdomain' );
```

#### Text Domain

Information about the textdomain find you in the codex, [the i18n part](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Text_Domains).

> If you're translating a plugin or a theme, you'll need to use a text
>   domain to denote all text belonging to that plugin. This increases
>   portability and plays better with already existing WordPress tools.
>   The text domain must match the “slug” of the plugin.

### Line ending error

Your second error is line ending problem. This create problems on several usage, also on the repository from wp.org. You can change this normally with your editor.